# how to remove the id property from the backbone.js url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The first time i send the request, the method seems to be POST and url seems to be fine, but the next time the url seems to be modified with an id getting attached to it.

```
=>
POST {"foo":"bar"} /things
<=
200 OK {"foo":"bar","id":"a36f933"}
```

The next time when i send the request, it seems there is an id getting generated.

```
=>
POST {"foo":"bar","id":"12345abc"} /things/12345abc
<=
200 OK {"foo":"bar","id":"12345abc"}
```

How can i avoid the id being send to my webservice, its throwing me a forbidden error.

Comment: can you show your backbone codes?

Comment: @Arrayoutofbound: i am using this class https://github.com/viezel/napp.alloy.adapter.restapi/blob/master/restapi.js, i don't know where to change in this code to reflect in my application.

Answer (score 2):

More info would help, but my bet would be:

- on the first call you are creating a new model. So it has no ID and the server will provide one.
- on the next calls, Backbone passes the ID so that the server knows which model has to be updated.

So the fix you have to make is on the server, not on Backbone.

Comment: https://github.com/viezel/napp.alloy.adapter.restapi/blob/master/restapi.js here is the code i am using.... can we change something here...